# How do I extract a list of Windows services and their status to a text file?

Tags: windows, export, services

I would like to get a text dump of the screen you see when running `services.msc` (except the Description column). This is so I can run a diff after installing different software that adds services to this screen.

Is this possible?

If it's helpful I have access to Powershell but don't know how to retrieve this type of information from it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the Services window, `Action > Export...` menu can give you the list as a .txt or .csv file. It gives you the description column as well, but you can easily delete it using a program like Excel.

You can also do this from Powershell.

```
Get-Service | Export-Csv -path "C:\services.csv"
```

Besides, you can filter the list. For example, you can get only the started services by executing the following command:

```
Get-Service | where {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Export-Csv -path "C:\services.csv"
```

Comment: This seems to only get my user's services or something.  I have some services that aren't showing up in this list?

Comment: If export with .csv, ensure `Unicode Text (Tab Delimited) (*.txt)` is used. If use Comma Delimited, the comma in Description field may overflow and mess up the output.

Comment: found here a way to export and import the configuration: http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/backup-windows-services-configuration/

Answer (score 13):

Without  using powershell, this lists running services:

```
 sc query > running_services.txt
```

This lists all services, running or not:

```
 sc query state= all > all_services.txt
```

Comment: PowerShell works better in this case because its output can be easily customised. But it's good to know there are other options, thanks!

Comment: PowerShell is nice, but not always on every machine.

Comment: Apparently WMI can do this too.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `net start` to get the list of the running services.

Answer (score 5):

I also needed the full path, so I wound up using

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | select Name, DisplayName, State, PathName | Export-Csv -path "C:\services.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server 8 (2012 beta), The Export option is gone.

Also the start menu is gone, and there's only a link to powershell on the taskbar. Thankfully all the programs are still there, I just had to manually create shortcuts to each one.

Comment: On Server 2012 R2, there exists option: `Action -> Export List...`