# How to count the number of services installed on a Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, services

I want to know how many services, the total number, are installed on my Server 2012. Using the `services.msc` I need to count by hand one by one.

I'm looking for a command line or similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract a list of Windows services and their status to a text file?](http://superuser.com/questions/144960/how-do-i-extract-a-list-of-windows-services-and-their-status-to-a-text-file)

Comment: Not a dupe as the dupe does not address counting any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 - Export List**
You can right click the computer name in services.msc, select "Export List" and then save as a CSV File:
[image]

From here, you can open it in Excel and count the rows (-1 for header - in this case, 162):[image]

If you don't have Excel, a tool like Notepad++ will give you a line count also.

---

**Option 2 - PowerShell**

```
(Get-Service | Measure-Object).Count
```

[image]
Quite literally - get a list of services, measure the returned list and display its "Count" property

---

**Bonus points** - both methods can be used on remote machines.

In services.msc, right click the computer and chose "Connect to another computer ..."

In powershell, use the `ComputerName` switch to get a remote computers service list:

```
(Get-Service -ComputerName "MyComputer.MyDomain.local" | Measure-Object).Count
```

Comment: For those more familiar with the `cmd` command line there is `sc query`. You will need to filter this (eg `sc query state= all | findstr SERVICE_NAME`) to give one line of output per service, and then a means of counting: you can use a script for this, or use `findstr` again to give a numbered listing (`sc query state= all | findstr SERVICE_NAME | findstr /n SERVICE_NAME`). Nothing like as elegant as using PowerShell, but an alternative which allows different subsets of the services to be enumerated, depending on the `sc` options selected. Note the space required between `state=` and `all`.

Comment: Some services are hidden and will not show in the services list.

Comment: @AFH That's already covered in my answer, it's easy to count the lines with `find` and hard with `findstr` ;)

Comment: @Moab Do you have an example of a hidden service? Do you know if they are listed by `sc` or `wmic`?

Comment: @DavidPostill - Sorry, my answer crossed with yours. I thought `find` had fallen into disuse, so I didn't check its options (I generally use `grep`): thanks for the prompt.

Comment: @DavidPostill, drivers run as services also, and are not displayed, if you look at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services, you will see All  Windows services.

Comment: @Moab Ah. Got it. I have updated my answer to count drivers as well.

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to know how many services (including drivers) are installed

As [moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928/moab) has pointed out in  comments:

> Some services are hidden and will not show in the services list.
>
> Drivers run as services also, and are not displayed, if you look at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`, you will see All Windows services.

**Solution 1 using `reg`**

You can use `reg` together with `find`:

```
F:\test>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services | find "" /v /c
541

F:\test>
```

Notes:

- `find "" /v /c` is used to count the number of lines

---

#### I want to know how many services (excluding drivers) are installed

Note:

- Drivers run as services also. See later for how to count installed drivers independently of services.

**Solution 1 using `sc`**

You can use `sc` together with `find`:

```
F:\test>sc query state= all | find /c "SERVICE_NAME"
201

F:\test>
```

Notes:

- Watch out for extra spaces:

  `SC QUERY state= all` Works

  `SC QUERY state =all` Fails!
- `find /c` is used to count the number of lines

**Solution 2 using `wmic`**

You can use `wmic` together with `find`:

```
F:\test>wmic service get name | find "" /v /c
203

F:\test>
```

Note:

- You need to subtract 2 from the result as `wmic` outputs a header ("Name") and a trailing blank line
- `find "" /v /c` is used to count the number of lines

---

#### I want to know how many drivers are installed

As [moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928/moab) has pointed out in  comments:

> Some services are hidden and will not show in the services list.
>
> Drivers run as services also, and are not displayed, if you look at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`, you will see All Windows services.

**Solution 1 using `driverquery`**

You can use `driverquery` together with `find`:

```
F:\test>driverquery | find "" /v /c
287

F:\test>
```

Note:

- You need to subtract 2 from the result as `driverquery` outputs 2 header lines
- `find "" /v /c` is used to count the number of lines

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [driverquery](http://ss64.com/nt/driverquery.html) - Display a list of all installed device drivers and their properties.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.
- [sc](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) - Service Control - Create, Start, Stop, Query or Delete any Windows SERVICE.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Export List` option in `services.msc` and choose to export it as a CSV file. Opening exported file in Excel (or any other csv capable reader) should give you the count of installed services.